# C++ Socket Connection on Linux

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new to C++ and am trying to setup a connection to a remote server but having problems getting it to work. Spec: Ubuntu 16.04, pre-installed g++ compiler and when I run the following code it returns "pre-standard C++":

```
if( __cplusplus == 201103L ) std::cout << "C++11\n" ;
else if( __cplusplus == 19971L ) std::cout << "C++98\n" ;
else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n" ;
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int client;
    int portNum = 80;
    bool isExit = false;
    int bufsize = 1024;
    char buffer[bufsize];
    const char ip[] = "216.58.210.36"; //google ip for test connection

    const char req[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.google.com"; //test
    char res[bufsize];

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client < 0) {
        cout << "\nError establishing socket..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\n=> Socket client has been created..." << endl;

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
    inet_aton(ip, &server_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(client,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == 0){
        cout << "=> Connection to the server port number: " << portNum << endl;
    }

    send(client, req, bufsize, 0);
    cout << "=> Awaiting confirmation from the server..." << endl;
    recv(client, buffer, bufsize, 0);
    cout << "=> Connection confirmed, response:" << buffer << endl;

    cout << res << endl;

    close(client);
    return 0;
}
```

The client is created and the socket connects but the code hangs on the call to recv() and no response is received. I'm assuming that's because the request I'm sending is in the wrong format/data type/etc. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong? Cheers!

Comment: What is your question, why you get the "pre-standard" output? Or about the `recv` issue?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about how you're compiling this code. If you want C++11, etc. you may need to enable that via flags. The current shipping compiler with Ubuntu is not "pre-standard C++". It's probably something like `201402` which you're not testing for. Use `>=` instead of `==`.

Comment: I also suggest you read the [`websocket` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/websocket/info). It's about something very different from your code.

Comment: [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is not to be confused with "socket used to retrieve web pages".

Comment: Furthermore, if a call like `connect` fails, you should not continue and attempt to send or receive using the socket. And you should also check for errors from the `send` and `recv` calls.

Comment: You should use `\r\n` as the newline sequence, and you need to send two newlines after the header.

Comment: As with anything internet protocol related, [RFC2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) can explain what you have to do to be compliant.

Comment: Yeah the question is why the hang on recv(). I will eventually be using the websocket protocol on it that's why that tag was there - anything different to consider in that regard? I'll try the suggestions, thanks guys. Is it safe to say you don't see any fundamental problems e.g. the data type of the message being passed to send() isn't correct or something like that?

Comment: The error code was not checked, so you don't know if the `send` was successful. Assuming it was, what does the server say about the message? Wireshark is often a helpful tool to see what is really happening.

Comment: I added the \n\n to the end of the request and it is working now. Thank you and sorry for the rather silly question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sent a complete HTTP request so the server is waiting for more data.

You need to use \r\n as your line separator and your request has to end in a blank line:

```
const char req[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Plus as others have commented you need to check for errors.

You are also sending 1024 bytes of data from a buffer which is much smaller.